Identification problems in the Heckit model
Consider the Heckit model with observables $(y,x,z,d)$ for which
\begin{align*}
y^*&=x'\theta+\epsilon\\
y&=dy^*\\
d&=\mathbb{1}(x'\pi_1+z'\pi_2\geq-\eta)\\
(\epsilon,\eta)&\perp (x,z)\\
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon\\\eta
\end{bmatrix}&\sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix}0\\0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_\epsilon^2&\sigma_{\epsilon\eta}\\
\sigma_{\epsilon\eta}&1
\end{bmatrix}\right)
\end{align*}
The variance of $\eta$ is normalized to 1 because otherwise $(\pi_1,\pi_2)$ are not identified.
Here are my questions for identification of this model:

How do I show that
\begin{align*}
E(y|\underline{x},\underline{z},d=1)&=\underline{x}'\theta+E(\epsilon|\underline{x},\underline{z},\underline{x}'\pi_1+\underline{z}'\pi_2\geq -\eta)\\
&=\underline{x}'\theta+\sigma_{\epsilon\eta}\lambda(\underline{x}'\pi_1+\underline{z}'\pi_2)
\end{align*}
where $\lambda(s)\equiv\frac{\phi(s)}{\Phi(s)}$?
How is $\pi_1,\pi_2$ identified? Why can we achieve this by a probit regression of $d$ onto $x$ and $z$?
If we do least squares regression of $y$ onto $x$ and $\lambda(x'\pi_1+z'\pi_2)$, why can we identify $\theta$ and $\sigma_{\epsilon\eta}$? Are there any additional conditions?

($\underline{x},\underline{z}$ are just fixed values)

You're describing the standard setup of the Heckman selection model. The detailed derivation can be found in many textbooks, such as chapter 16.5 of Cameron & Trivedi (2005).
